# What means 's' and 'u' letters on CPU utilization in iperf3 command with -V?

Tags: bandwidth, cpu-usage, measurement, iperf, utilization

i have very simple question: When Im using Iperf3 with my server and on client i add paramater -V which mean it will display more detailed information it's display information about CPU utilization on server and client. 
Example of displayed information:

```
CPU Utilization: local/sender 0.2% (0.1%u/0.1%s), remote/receiver 11.5% (7.7%u/3.9%s)
```

I don't know what these letters 'u' and 's' mean so that is my question, looking for your help.

Comment: My guess - user and system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DavidPostill's comment is correct: they stand for **u**ser and **s**ystem, respectively. To prove it, let's look at [the code](https://github.com/esnet/iperf).

We find the string "CPU Utilization" [in `iperf_locale.c`](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/099244ec686b620393e9845478a554b1c7ca5c8b/src/iperf_locale.c#L362). This file appears to have all the language-specific strings, and the variable for the line that reports CPU usage is called `report_cpu`.

```
const char report_cpu[] =
"CPU Utilization: %s/%s %.1f%% (%.1f%%u/%.1f%%s), %s/%s %.1f%% (%.1f%%u/%.1f%%s)\n";
```

We find that variable used [in `iperf_api.c`](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/ad2a706fd194381c9a1f571b93d16c3edbd4d114/src/iperf_api.c#L2545). The function used there seems to be more or less similar to `printf`, which takes a format string (our `report_cpu`) and replaces all the placeholders in it with a human-readable version of the given variables.

```
iperf_printf(test, report_cpu, report_local, test->sender?report_sender:report_receiver, test->cpu_util[0], test->cpu_util[1], test->cpu_util[2], report_remote, test->sender?report_receiver:report_sender, test->remote_cpu_util[0], test->remote_cpu_util[1], test->remote_cpu_util[2]);
```

The fourth and fifth placeholders, the `%.1f`s inside the parentheses, are what we're investigating. It looks like the first two parameters to the function are some kind of context and the template string, respectively, so we'll start counting at the `report_local` one. The fourth is `test->cpu_util[1]`. Some digging reveals that these three-valued `cpu_util` arrays are generated [in `iperf_util.c`](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/099244ec686b620393e9845478a554b1c7ca5c8b/src/iperf_util.c#L178). The interesting part is at the very end of the `cpu_util` function:

```
pcpu[0] = (((ctemp - clast) * 1000000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) / timediff) * 100;
pcpu[1] = (userdiff / timediff) * 100;
pcpu[2] = (systemdiff / timediff) * 100;
```

Slots 1 and 2 are indeed based on the user time and the system time, respectively, while slot 0 is the total usage.